# Simple adding in Python

Tags: python, parameters, addition

Funnction Name: lone_sum

Parameters
a : an integer value
b : an integer value
c : an integer value

Given 3 integer values, a, b, c, return their sum. However, if one of the values is the same as another of the values, it does not count towards the sum.

Return Value: The sum of a, b, and c, leaving out like values.

I have this and I'm completely lost with it! What am I missing?

```
def lone_sum(a,b,c):
    t=0
    if a!=b and b!=c:
        t=a+b+c
    elif a==b and a!=c:
        t= a+c
    elif a==c and a!=b:
        t=a+b
    elif b==c and b!=a:
        t=b+a
    elif a==b and b==c:
        t=0
    return t
```

Comment: Your last `elif` is not consistent with the others: if all 3 are equals according to the other "elifs" you are considering only one of the "dups" but in the last elif you don't consider any of them.

Answer (score 3):

## Problems :

#### 1)

```
a!=b and b!=c
```

This test isn't enough : `a` could be equal to `c`. (e.g. `1,0,1`)

#### 2)

If `a==b and b==c`, total should be `a`, not `0`, right?

## Solutions

#### Modified code

```
def lone_sum(a,b,c):
    t=0
    if a!=b and b!=c and a!=c:
        t = a + b + c
    elif a==b and a!=c:
        t = a + c
    elif a==c and a!=b:
        t = a + b
    elif b==c and b!=a:
        t = b + a
    elif a==b and b==c:
        t = a
    return t
```

#### Alternative

You could simply pack the values into a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) to remove the duplicates :

```
def lone_sum(a,b,c):
    return sum(set([a,b,c]))

print(lone_sum(1,2,3))
# 6
print(lone_sum(1,2,2))
# 3
print(lone_sum(3,3,3))
# 3
```

Note that this behaviour corresponds to your description, not to your code (last example would be `0`).

As a bonus, it's trivial to adapt the function to `n` values :

```
def lone_sum(*values):
    return sum(set(values))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use **Set** to work with unique values, and **reduce** to sum them:

```
from sets import Set

def lone_sum(a,b,c):
   nums = Set([a,b,c])
   return reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, nums)
```